# SIRF3 and styleSwitcher, how to force the font.swf to reload in the browser cache?

Tags: sifr, refresh

Alright after having searched thr whole web for my answer, I hope to have someone to help me on this plezzzz.

I'm working with a php styleswitcher to give my website a day/night look and i'm using 2 sifr-config files to handle the color changes needed for the text to keep be readble on both backgrounds color.

(let's say I'm writing in white with a black background and vice-versa)

In theory it's working great, BUT i'm obliged to hit F5 to force the refresh of the sirf SWF on style change, otherwise my browser keeps the same font file all time, I've tried meta no-cache, different variables names, differents swf's, ...I've tried to add a ramdom number at the end of thefont.swf?... I think it could be the solution but it's not working.

Do you see a solution?
Many many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to change the sIFR font when the style switches? You'll have to reapply sIFR for this to work, which I guess is what the reload does.

Look into "sIFR rollback" on how to undo the replacements, and then run the replacements again with the new Flash file. You could also try and embed two fonts in one sIFR 3 movie and use the dynamic `changeCSS` method to switch to the other font family.